Is there any InputMask for IBAN (BlazorInputMask)?
I try to create a component in Blazor for IBAN. But someone adviced me using BlazorInputMask. I only see examples for phone numbers.
Is there any InputMask for a correct IBAN?
I only can input the digits. When you have an IBAN NL98 INGB 00007 6543 21
Then you get as result NL98 AAAA 0007 6543 21.
@{
    string mask = "/[^A-Z0-9]/"; 
    if (OnlyDutch)
    {
        mask = "NL00 AAAA 0000 0000 00";
    }

}

<InputMask @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
           name="@AttributeName"
           id="@Id"
           class="@CssClass"
           @bind-Value="@stringValue"
           data-mask=@mask
           placeholder="NL00 BANK 0000 0000 00"
           @oninput="OnInput"
           @onchange="this.OnValueChanged" />


What exactly are you asking? Do you need help creating a regex for IBANs?

It's just the mask. NL00 AAAA 0000 0000 00. Do you know what is an IBAN? That's a Bankaccount. I want an mask for an Bankaccount. That's all,.

And I want to use BlazorInputMask.

The Mask would depend on the Country Code in it, though. Different countries have different length IBANs. All you can generally say is it has 2 alphabetical chars, then 2 places checksum and the rest depends on country. It has an absolute max length of 34 chars (if I remember correctly).

I know. For the international IBAN's I use the default Mask. We have in the FluentValidator code for checking if the IBAN is correct. And that works fine.

But which characters do I have to use for Capitals. AAAA doesn't work and LLLL doesn't work either.

BlazorInputMask is based on imaskjs, so you will have to look at the docs of that.

You could use a regex mask (like "/[^A-Z0-9]/" in your example) and insert one of the many regex you find via googling "iban regex". Make sure you enclose your regex with slashes / like it's done in your example.

Then I try this. And it doesn't work.
string regexPattern = @"^NL\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{10}$";
mask = "/" + regexPattern + "/";

theres a nuget for iban validation. I personally never used it. https://github.com/skwasjer/IbanNet

Thank you. I will see if there is any code about a IBAN-mask that I can use. But the first what I saw was something about validation. That is something in our system that already works fine. Also with a component.
